# Using Comment to record every change in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use comment to record every change in cells but Excel crashes every time when the code is execute.

For the Undo part, is there any better ways for me to record the old value and new value ?

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each r In Target

    new_value = r.Value
    Application.Undo
    old_value = r.Value
    r.Value = new_value

    If r.Value = "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.AddComment.Text Application.UserName & " has added " & new_value & " at " & Now

    ElseIf r.Value <> "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.AddComment.Text Application.UserName & " has changed from " & old_value & " to " & new_value & " at " & Now

    ElseIf Not r.Value = "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.Comment.Text Application.UserName & " has changed from " & old_value & " to " & new_value & " at " & Now

    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use version control. You may want to store the file in SharePoint. SharePoint will record the changes for you.

Comment: Otherwise, you can write all the changes to a log file stored on a share folder on your network.

Comment: So, any error and if yes, what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid Excel running into an endless loop you need to turn off events

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each r In Target

    new_value = r.Value
    Application.Undo
    old_value = r.Value
    r.Value = new_value

    If r.Value = "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.AddComment.Text Application.UserName & " has added " & new_value & " at " & Now

    ElseIf r.Value <> "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.AddComment.Text Application.UserName & " has changed from " & old_value & " to " & new_value & " at " & Now

    ElseIf Not r.Value = "" And r.Comment Is Nothing Then
        r.Comment.Text Application.UserName & " has changed from " & old_value & " to " & new_value & " at " & Now

    End If

Next

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Now you can check if your code is doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Hi, Storax, could you advise me how to handle the error while I am using the VBA code to update cells value rather change it directly? As using VBA code to update will cause an error on line "Application.Undo"

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I'd suggest to open an new question and explain more detailed what your problem is and what kind of error you get on the line `Application.Undo`.